# Updating CSS and rendering tooltip on hover over ggplot happening in the wrong order

Tags: css, r, ggplot2, shinydashboard

I have constructed a dummy app here that produces hover messages for ggplot, and to make sure they stay within the screen boundaries, I wrote some calculations to determine the needed css corrections and send those to the server.

It is based on the first attempt to keep hover messages in place here: [SOquestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57039988/how-to-prevent-ggplot-hoveropts-messages-to-go-off-screen-with-css/57054202#57054202)
Since then I have changed to sending modified css code to alter the offset of the tooltip.

The problem is however, it seems, that the table is build before the css is send to the server, and I can't seem to find a way to change the order in which these two things happen.

```
require('shiny')
require('ggplot2')
require('DT')
require('shinyjs')

ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  
  headerPanel("Hover off the page"),
  sidebarPanel(width = 2
  ),
  mainPanel(
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
    tags$head(
      tags$style('
                 #my_tooltip {
                 position: absolute;
                 pointer-events:none;
                 width: 10;
                 z-index: 100;
                 padding: 0;
                 font-size:10px;
                 line-height:0.6em
                 }
                 ')
    ),
    
    plotOutput('FP1Plot1' ,
               width = 1000,
               height = 800,
               hover = hoverOpts(id = 'FP1Plot_1_hover', delay = 0)          
    ),
    
    uiOutput("my_tooltip"),

    style = 'width:1250px'
      )
    )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # ranges <- reactiveValues()
  
  
  output$FP1Plot1 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, color = as.factor(cyl))) + geom_point() #+
      # coord_cartesian(xlim = ranges[[paste('FP1Plot1',  'x', sep = '')]], 
      #                 ylim = ranges[[paste('FP1Plot1',  'y', sep = '')]]
      # )          
  })
  
  
  

  # turn the hovers into 1 single reactive containing the needed information
  hoverReact <- reactive({
    ## in my real app I observer hover of all sub plots of all stages (7 pages with a multilot object)
    ## followed by code to store the page ID and plot NR as elements in hoverReact()
    hover <-  input[['FP1Plot_1_hover']]
    
    if(is.null(hover)) return(NULL)
     hover
    
  })
  
  ## debounce the reaction to calm down shiny
  hoverReact_D <- hoverReact %>% debounce(100)  ## attempt to stop hoverData <- reactive({}) from firing too often, which is needed when you have 10k point scatter plots.....
  
  hoverData <- reactive({
    hover <- hoverReact_D() 
    if(is.null(hover)) return(NULL)
    ## in my multi plot multi data frame I look up which dataframe to grab based on hover$plot_id as well as which x and y parameter are plotted
    hoverDF <- nearPoints(mtcars, coordinfo = hover, threshold = 15, maxpoints = 1, xvar = 'wt', yvar = 'mpg')
    hoverDF
  })
  
  
  
  hoverPos <- reactive({
    ## here I look up the position information of the hover whenevver hoverReact_D and hoverData change 
    hover <- hoverReact_D()
    hoverDF <- hoverData()
    if(is.null(hover)) return(NULL)
    if(nrow(hoverDF) == 0) return(NULL)
    
    ## in my real app the data is already 
    X <- hoverDF$wt[1]
    Y <- hoverDF$mpg[1]
    
    left_pct <- 
      (X - hover$domain$left) / (hover$domain$right - hover$domain$left)

    top_pct <- 
      (hover$domain$top - Y) / (hover$domain$top - hover$domain$bottom)  

    left_px <- 
      (hover$range$left + left_pct * (hover$range$right - hover$range$left)) / 
      hover$img_css_ratio$x 

    top_px <- 
      (hover$range$top + top_pct * (hover$range$bottom - hover$range$top)) / 
      hover$img_css_ratio$y 

    list(top = top_px, left = left_px)
  })
  

  

  observeEvent(hoverPos(), {
  req(hoverPos())
    hover <- hoverPos()
    if(is.null(hover)) return(NULL)
    
    
    offX <- if(hover$left  > 350) {-400} else {30}
    offY <- if(hover$top  > 350) {-290} else {10 }
    
print('sending css') 
print(offY)

    runjs(paste0( "$(document).ready(function() {",
                  "setTimeout(function(){",
                         "$('[id^=FP1Plot]').mousemove(function(e) {",
                         "$('#my_tooltip').show();",         
                         "$('#my_tooltip').css({",         
                         "top: (e.offsetY +", offY, " ) + 'px',",
                         "left: (e.offsetX +", offX, ") + 'px'",     
                         "});",     
                         "});",     
                         "})});") )
    
    
}, priority = -1)
  
  
  output$GGHoverTable <- DT::renderDataTable({  
    
    df <- hoverData()
    if(!is.null(df)) {
      if(nrow(df)){
        df <- df[1,]
        DT::datatable(t(df), colnames = rep("", nrow(df)),
                      options = list(dom='t',ordering=F, autowidth = T))
      }
    }
  })
  
  
  output$my_tooltip <- renderUI({
    req(hoverData())
    req(nrow(hoverData())>0 )
    print('sending table')
    wellPanel(
      dataTableOutput('GGHoverTable'),
      style = 'background-color: #FFFFFFE6;padding:10px; width:400px;border-color:#339fff')
  
    })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Have you considered using tooltips or popovers from the shinyBS package?

Comment: Can they hold plot and table objects? I didn't think of those as I thought they didn't. Will try some things today

Comment: Remove `$(document).ready(function` and `setTimeout`. And set `priority=1` instead of `-1`. The result is not bad.

Comment: I have the feeling it still skips the first render Stephane (that is if you go straight from point to point without hesitation, between 2 quadrants)

Comment: Ok, I think it's working well enough actually. Could it be that the fact that mousemove is still in there that it needs another move before it updates? if so, how does the script look without it, as we need to capture e.offsetX and Y from mousemove I suppose

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Is it better if you do `$('[id^=FP1Plot]').off('mousemove.x').on('mousemove.x', function(e) {` ? This removes the previous mousemove handler.

Comment: I think so yes. Now I'm struggling to get it work when the nr of plots increases. Will post new question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57075496/location-of-hover-message-when-there-are-multiple-plots-goes-wrong

Comment: @ Simon, tried your suggestion too, can't get it to work though. Tooltips won't load without giving error messages due to the content in my attempts. Feel free to post a working solution for us to learn from