# Location of hover message when there are multiple plots goes wrong

Tags: javascript, css, r, ggplot2, hover

In the hunt for custom build hover messages, and making sure they stay on the screen I managed to fix the css position updating with this question: [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57066720/updating-css-and-rendering-tooltip-on-hover-over-ggplot-happening-in-the-wrong-o?noredirect=1#comment100666265_57066720),
but in my real app, the nr op plots can be set by the user, who will be autoscaled:
1-20 plots
1-4 columns

On hover, both plots produce `px` values of vertical and horizontal position, and both plots seem to give similar values. 
This then triggers the calculation of offset correction depending on which part of the plot the coordinates are in (move up/down, left/right depending on which quarter of the plot)

```
offX <- if(hover$left  > 350) {-90} else {50}
offY <- if(hover$top  > 350) {-270} else {30 }
```

The demo app shows that both plots produce the same correction values, which should be added to the `e.offsetY`  and `e.offsetX`

The plots are called `FP1Plot1` and `FP1Plot2` , the last nr indicating the sequence nr, the first part the page of my app they are on.

This block should send the new coordinates for the tooltip, but they seem to always be linked to the 1st plot on the left. This because it is linking it to the grouped output object 'FP1PlotDoubleplot'. I can't figure out how to link it to the actual single plot the hover is currently over:

```
runjs(paste0( "$('[id^=FP1Plot]').off('mousemove.x').on('mousemove.x', function(e) {",
                  "$('#my_tooltip').show();",
                  "$('#my_tooltip').css({",
                  "top: (e.offsetY +", offY, " ) + 'px',",
                  "left: (e.offsetX +", offX, ") + 'px'",
                  "});",
                  "});") )
```

[image]

**Problem with multiple plots**

```
require('shiny')
require('ggplot2')
require('DT')
require('shinyjs')
library('shinyBS')

ui <- pageWithSidebar(

  headerPanel("Hover off the page"),
  sidebarPanel(width = 2,

               verbatimTextOutput('leftPix'),
               verbatimTextOutput('topPix')
  ),
  mainPanel(
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
    tags$head(
      tags$style('
                 #my_tooltip {
                 position: absolute;
                 pointer-events:none;
                 width: 10;
                 z-index: 100;
                 padding: 0;
                 font-size:10px;
                 line-height:0.6em
                 }
                 ')
    ),

uiOutput('FP1PlotDoubleplot'),

    uiOutput('my_tooltip'),
    style = 'width:1250px'
      )
    )

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # ranges <- reactiveValues()


  output$FP1Plot1 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, color = as.factor(cyl))) + geom_point() 

  })

  output$FP1Plot2 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, color = as.factor(cyl))) + geom_point() 
  })

  output$FP1PlotDoubleplot<- renderUI({

    plot_output_list <- list()

    for(i in 1:2) {
      plot_output_list <- append(plot_output_list,list(
        div(id = paste0('div', 'FP1Plot', i),
            wellPanel(
              plotOutput(paste0('FP1Plot', i),
                         width = 500,
                         height = 600,
                         hover = hoverOpts(id = paste('FP1Plot', i, "hover", sep = '_'), delay = 0)
              ),
              style = paste('border-color:#339fff; border-width:2px; background-color: #fff; width:',  540, 'px; height:', 680, 'px', sep = '')),
            style = paste('display: inline-block; margin: 2px; width:', 540, 'px; height:', 680, 'px', sep = ''))

      ))
    }
    do.call(tagList, plot_output_list)

  })








  # turn the hovers into 1 single reactive containing the needed information
  hoverReact <- reactive({
    eg <- expand.grid(c('FP1Plot'), 1:2)
    plotids <- sprintf('%s_%s', eg[,1], eg[,2])
    names(plotids) <- plotids

    hovers <- lapply(plotids, function(key) input[[paste0(key, '_hover')]])

    notNull <- sapply(hovers, Negate(is.null))
    if(any(notNull)){
      plotid <- names(which(notNull))
      plothoverid <- paste0(plotid, "_hover")

      hover <- input[[plothoverid]]
      if(is.null(hover)) return(NULL)
      hover
    }
  })

  ## debounce the reaction to calm down shiny
  hoverReact_D <- hoverReact %>% debounce(100)  ## attempt to stop hoverData <- reactive({}) from firing too often, which is needed when you have 10k point scatter plots.....

  hoverData <- reactive({
    hover <- hoverReact_D() 
    if(is.null(hover)) return(NULL)
    ## in my multi plot multi data frame I look up which dataframe to grab based on hover$plot_id as well as which x and y parameter are plotted
    hoverDF <- nearPoints(mtcars, coordinfo = hover, threshold = 15, maxpoints = 1, xvar = 'wt', yvar = 'mpg')
    hoverDF
  })



  hoverPos <- reactive({
    ## here I look up the position information of the hover whenevver hoverReact_D and hoverData change 
    hover <- hoverReact_D()
    hoverDF <- hoverData()
    if(is.null(hover)) return(NULL)
    if(nrow(hoverDF) == 0) return(NULL)

    ## in my real app the data is already 
    X <- hoverDF$wt[1]
    Y <- hoverDF$mpg[1]

    left_pct <- 
      (X - hover$domain$left) / (hover$domain$right - hover$domain$left)

    top_pct <- 
      (hover$domain$top - Y) / (hover$domain$top - hover$domain$bottom)  

    left_px <- 
      (hover$range$left + left_pct * (hover$range$right - hover$range$left)) / 
      hover$img_css_ratio$x 

    top_px <- 
      (hover$range$top + top_pct * (hover$range$bottom - hover$range$top)) / 
      hover$img_css_ratio$y 

    list(top = top_px, left = left_px)
  })




  observeEvent(hoverPos(), {
  req(hoverPos())
    hover <- hoverPos()
    if(is.null(hover)) return(NULL)

    offX <- if(hover$left  > 350) {-90} else {50}
    offY <- if(hover$top  > 350) {-270} else {30 }

    output$leftPix <- renderPrint({ offX[1]})
    output$topPix <- renderPrint({ offY[1]})

    runjs(paste0( "$('[id^=FP1Plot]').off('mousemove.x').on('mousemove.x', function(e) {",
                         "$('#my_tooltip').show();",
                         "$('#my_tooltip').css({",
                         "top: (e.offsetY +", offY, " ) + 'px',",
                         "left: (e.offsetX +", offX, ") + 'px'",
                         "});",
                         "});") )

  })

  output$GGHoverTable <- DT::renderDataTable({  

    df <- hoverData()
    if(!is.null(df)) {
      if(nrow(df)){
        df <- df[1,]
        DT::datatable(t(df), colnames = rep("", nrow(df)),
                      options = list(dom='t',ordering=F))
      }
    }
  })


  output$my_tooltip <- renderUI({
    req(hoverData())
    req(nrow(hoverData())>0 )
    wellPanel(
      dataTableOutput('GGHoverTable'),
      style = 'background-color: #FFFFFFE6;padding:10px; width:400px;border-color:#339fff; width:auto')  
    })  

  }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Working nicely with 1 plot**

```
require('shiny')
require('ggplot2')
require('DT')
require('shinyjs')
library('shinyBS')

ui <- pageWithSidebar(

  headerPanel("Hover off the page"),
  sidebarPanel(width = 2
  ),
  mainPanel(
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
    tags$head(
      tags$style('
                 #my_tooltip {
                 position: absolute;
                 pointer-events:none;
                 width: 10;
                 z-index: 100;
                 padding: 0;
                 font-size:10px;
                 line-height:0.6em
                 }
                 ')
    ),

    plotOutput('FP1Plot1' ,
               width = 1000,
               height = 800,
               hover = hoverOpts(id = 'FP1Plot_1_hover', delay = 0)          
    ),

    uiOutput('my_tooltip'),
    style = 'width:1250px'
      )
    )

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$FP1Plot1 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, color = as.factor(cyl))) + geom_point() #+
  })

  # turn the hovers into 1 single reactive containing the needed information
  hoverReact <- reactive({
    ## in my real app I observer hover of all sub plots of all stages (7 pages with a multilot object)
    ## followed by code to store the page ID and plot NR as elements in hoverReact()
    hover <-  input[['FP1Plot_1_hover']]

    if(is.null(hover)) return(NULL)
     hover

  })

  ## debounce the reaction to calm down shiny
  hoverReact_D <- hoverReact %>% debounce(100)  ## attempt to stop hoverData <- reactive({}) from firing too often, which is needed when you have 10k point scatter plots.....

  hoverData <- reactive({
    hover <- hoverReact_D() 
    if(is.null(hover)) return(NULL)
    ## in my multi plot multi data frame I look up which dataframe to grab based on hover$plot_id as well as which x and y parameter are plotted
    hoverDF <- nearPoints(mtcars, coordinfo = hover, threshold = 15, maxpoints = 1, xvar = 'wt', yvar = 'mpg')
    hoverDF
  })



  hoverPos <- reactive({
    ## here I look up the position information of the hover whenevver hoverReact_D and hoverData change 
    hover <- hoverReact_D()
    hoverDF <- hoverData()
    if(is.null(hover)) return(NULL)
    if(nrow(hoverDF) == 0) return(NULL)

    ## in my real app the data is already 
    X <- hoverDF$wt[1]
    Y <- hoverDF$mpg[1]

    left_pct <- 
      (X - hover$domain$left) / (hover$domain$right - hover$domain$left)

    top_pct <- 
      (hover$domain$top - Y) / (hover$domain$top - hover$domain$bottom)  

    left_px <- 
      (hover$range$left + left_pct * (hover$range$right - hover$range$left)) / 
      hover$img_css_ratio$x 

    top_px <- 
      (hover$range$top + top_pct * (hover$range$bottom - hover$range$top)) / 
      hover$img_css_ratio$y 

    list(top = top_px, left = left_px)
  })




  observeEvent(hoverPos(), {
  req(hoverPos())
    hover <- hoverPos()
    if(is.null(hover)) return(NULL)

    offX <- if(hover$left  > 350) {-400} else {30}
    offY <- if(hover$top  > 350) {-290} else {10 }

    runjs(paste0( "$('[id^=FP1Plot]').mousemove(function(e) {",
                         "$('#my_tooltip').show();",
                         "$('#my_tooltip').css({",
                         "top: (e.offsetY +", offY, " ) + 'px',",
                         "left: (e.offsetX +", offX, ") + 'px'",
                         "});",
                         "});") )

  })

  output$GGHoverTable <- DT::renderDataTable({  

    df <- hoverData()
    if(!is.null(df)) {
      if(nrow(df)){
        df <- df[1,]
        DT::datatable(t(df), colnames = rep("", nrow(df)),
                      options = list(dom='t',ordering=F, autowidth = T))
      }
    }
  })


  output$my_tooltip <- renderUI({
    req(hoverData())
    req(nrow(hoverData())>0 )
    wellPanel(
      dataTableOutput('GGHoverTable'),
      style = 'background-color: #FFFFFFE6;padding:10px; width:400px;border-color:#339fff')

    })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**PS follow up to make the offset smarter**

I attempted to write some javascript to grab object sizes to base the offset flip point based on that, but so far not working

```
sizejs <- function(ID){
  sprintf(paste(
    "var element = document.getElementById({id: %s);",
    "var positionInfo = element.getBoundingClientRect();",
    "var height = positionInfo.height;",
    "var width = positionInfo.width;",
    "    Shiny.setInputValue(objectHeight, height);",
    "    Shiny.setInputValue(objectWidth, width);",
    sep = "\n"
  ), ID)
}
```

and then: 
`runjs(sizejs('TooltipDiv'))` 
to get the size of the tooltip (renamed to `div('TooltipDiv'...` instead of `wellPanel` 
but hopefully also to check the size of the plots (in a dynamic layout this changes with nr of plots)

**EDIT: Current best working version**

moving to a new question for the details about multi column/rows and not going outside the limits
So far I have this for 2 plot scenario

```
require('shiny')
  require('ggplot2')
  require('DT')
  require('shinyjs')
  library('shinyBS')

  ui <- pageWithSidebar(

    headerPanel("Hover off the page"),
    sidebarPanel(width = 2,

                 verbatimTextOutput('leftPix'),
                 verbatimTextOutput('topPix')
    ),
    mainPanel(
      shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
      tags$head(
        tags$style('
                   #my_tooltip {
                   position: absolute;
                   pointer-events:none;
                   width: 10;
                   z-index: 100;
                   padding: 0;
                   font-size:10px;
                   line-height:0.6em
                   }
                   ')
        ),

      uiOutput('FP1PlotDoubleplot'),

      uiOutput('my_tooltip'),
      style = 'width:1250px'
        )
      )

  server <- function(input, output, session) {

    # ranges <- reactiveValues()


    output$FP1Plot_1 <- renderPlot({
      ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, color = as.factor(cyl))) + geom_point() 

    })

    output$FP1Plot_2 <- renderPlot({
      ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, color = as.factor(cyl))) + geom_point() 
    })

    output$FP1PlotDoubleplot<- renderUI({

      plot_output_list <- list()

      for(i in 1:2) {
        plot_output_list <- append(plot_output_list,list(
          div(id = paste0('div', 'FP1Plot_', i),
              wellPanel(
                plotOutput(paste0('FP1Plot_', i),
                           width = 500,
                           height = 600,
                           hover = hoverOpts(id = paste('FP1Plot', i, "hover", sep = '_'), delay = 0)
                ),
                style = paste('border-color:#339fff; border-width:2px; background-color: #fff; width:',  540, 'px; height:', 680, 'px', sep = '')),
              style = paste('display: inline-block; margin: 2px; width:', 540, 'px; height:', 680, 'px', sep = ''))

        ))
      }
      do.call(tagList, plot_output_list)

    })

    # turn the hovers into 1 single reactive containing the needed information
    hoverReact <- reactive({
      eg <- expand.grid(c('FP1Plot'), 1:2)
      plotids <- sprintf('%s_%s', eg[,1], eg[,2])
      names(plotids) <- plotids

      hovers <- lapply(plotids, function(key) input[[paste0(key, '_hover')]])

      notNull <- sapply(hovers, Negate(is.null))
      if(any(notNull)){
        plotid <- names(which(notNull))
        plothoverid <- paste0(plotid, "_hover")

        hover <- input[[plothoverid]]
        if(is.null(hover)) return(NULL)
        hover
      }
    })

    ## debounce the reaction to calm down shiny
    hoverReact_D <- hoverReact %>% debounce(100)  ## attempt to stop hoverData <- reactive({}) from firing too often, which is needed when you have 10k point scatter plots.....

    hoverData <- reactive({
      hover <- hoverReact_D() 
      if(is.null(hover)) return(NULL)
      ## in my multi plot multi data frame I look up which dataframe to grab based on hover$plot_id as well as which x and y parameter are plotted
      hoverDF <- nearPoints(mtcars, coordinfo = hover, threshold = 15, maxpoints = 1, xvar = 'wt', yvar = 'mpg')
      hoverDF
    })



    hoverPos <- reactive({
      ## here I look up the position information of the hover whenevver hoverReact_D and hoverData change 
      hover <- hoverReact_D()
      hoverDF <- hoverData()
      if(is.null(hover)) return(NULL)
      if(nrow(hoverDF) == 0) return(NULL)

      ## in my real app the data is already 
      X <- hoverDF$wt[1]
      Y <- hoverDF$mpg[1]

      left_pct <- 
        (X - hover$domain$left) / (hover$domain$right - hover$domain$left)

      top_pct <- 
        (hover$domain$top - Y) / (hover$domain$top - hover$domain$bottom)  

      left_px <- 
        (hover$range$left + left_pct * (hover$range$right - hover$range$left)) / 
        hover$img_css_ratio$x 

      top_px <- 
        (hover$range$top + top_pct * (hover$range$bottom - hover$range$top)) / 
        hover$img_css_ratio$y 

      list(top = top_px, left = left_px)
    })




    observeEvent(hoverPos(), {
      req(hoverPos())
      hover <- hoverPos()
      if(is.null(hover)) return(NULL)

      offX <- if(hover$left  > 350) {-125} else {10}
      offY <- if(hover$top  > 350) {-290} else {10 }

      output$leftPix <- renderPrint({ offX[1]})
      output$topPix <- renderPrint({ offY[1]})

      runjs(paste0( "$('[id=FP1PlotDoubleplot]').off('mousemove.x').on('mousemove.x', function(e) {",
                    "$('#my_tooltip').show();",
                    "$('#my_tooltip').css({",
                    "top: (e.offsetY + e.target.offsetTop+", offY, " ) + 'px',",
                    "left: (e.offsetX + e.target.offsetLeft +", offX, ") + 'px'",
                    "});",
                    "});") )

    })

    output$GGHoverTable <- DT::renderDataTable({  

      df <- hoverData()
      if(!is.null(df)) {
        if(nrow(df)){
          df <- df[1,]
          DT::datatable(t(df), colnames = rep("", nrow(df)),
                        options = list(dom='t',ordering=F))
        }
      }
    })


    output$my_tooltip <- renderUI({
      req(hoverData())
      req(nrow(hoverData())>0 )
      wellPanel(
        DT::dataTableOutput('GGHoverTable'),
        style = 'background-color: #FFFFFFE6;padding:10px; width:400px;border-color:#339fff; width:auto')  
    })  

  }

  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**UPDATE 4**

This code is simplified to avoid unnecessary steps and seems to work quite well:

```
runjs(paste0( "$('[id=FP1PlotMSPggplot]').off('mousemove.x').on('mousemove.x', function(e) {",
                  "  $('#my_tooltip').show();",
                  "  var tooltip = document.getElementById('my_tooltip');",
                  "  var rect = tooltip.getBoundingClientRect();",
                  "  var FrameID = document.getElementById('FP1PlotMSPggplot');",
                  "  var frame = FrameID.getBoundingClientRect();",
                  "  var hoverLeft = ", hover$left, ";",
                  "  var hoverTop = ", hover$top, ";", 
                  "  var imgWidth = e.target.width;",
                  "  var imgHeight = e.target.height;",
                  "  var offX = 2 * hoverLeft > imgWidth ? -rect.width  +15: 35;",
                  "  var offY = 2 * hoverTop > imgHeight ? -rect.height + 80 : 90;",
                  "  var shiftY = e.offsetY + e.target.offsetTop + offY;",
                  "  var shiftX = e.offsetX + e.target.offsetLeft + offX;",
                  "  shiftY = shiftY < 0 ? e.offsetY + e.target.offsetTop + 10 : shiftY;",
                  "  $('#my_tooltip').css({",
                  "    top: shiftY + 'px',",
                  "    left: shiftX + 'px'",
                  "  });",
                  "});") )
```

The only hardcoded value still gives a bit of an issue:

```
"  var offX = 2 * hoverLeft > imgWidth ? -rect.width  +15: 35;",
                  "  var offY = 2 * hoverTop > imgHeight ? -rect.height + 80 : 90;",
```

the +15, 35, 80 and 90 in here seem to depend on where on the page (screen)
the main div is placed (which is not exactly the same everywhere in my app. 
I wonder if there is another `e.target...` we can use. 
In the app above this update, this refers to changes in the positioning of `uiOutput('FP1PlotDoubleplot')` that affects these numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to replace `dataTableOutput` with `DT::dataTableOutput`, otherwise the tooltips were empty.

The tooltips seem to be well positioned by doing:

```
offX <- if(hover$left  > 350) {-90} else {0}
offY <- if(hover$top  > 350) {-270} else {30 }

runjs(paste0( "$('[id=FP1PlotDoubleplot]').off('mousemove.x').on('mousemove.x', function(e) {",
              "$('#my_tooltip').show();",
              "$('#my_tooltip').css({",
              "top: (e.offsetY +", offY, " ) + 'px',",
              "left: (e.offsetX + e.target.offsetLeft +", offX, ") + 'px'",
              "});",
              "});") )
```

---

## Edit

Here is a way to automatically calculate the offsets:

```
offX <- if(hover$left  > 270) {1000} else {0} # 270 = 540/2 (540 is the width of FP1PlotDoubleplot)
offY <- if(hover$top  > 350) {1000} else {30}

runjs(paste0( "$('[id=FP1PlotDoubleplot]').off('mousemove.x').on('mousemove.x', function(e) {",
              "  $('#my_tooltip').show();",
              "  var tooltip = document.getElementById('my_tooltip');",
              "  var rect = tooltip.getBoundingClientRect();",
              "  var offX = ", offX, ";",
              "  var offY = ", offY, ";",
              "  offX = offX === 1000 ? -rect.width : offX;",
              "  offY = offY === 1000 ? -rect.height+30 : offY;",
              "  $('#my_tooltip').css({",
              "    top: e.offsetY + offY + 'px',",
              "    left: e.offsetX + e.target.offsetLeft + offX + 'px'",
              "  });",
              "});") )
```

---

## Edit

A better way, which does not require to enter the dimensions of the plots:

```
  observeEvent(hoverPos(), {
    req(hoverPos())
    hover <- hoverPos()
    if(is.null(hover)) return(NULL)

    runjs(paste0( "$('[id=FP1PlotDoubleplot]').off('mousemove.x').on('mousemove.x', function(e) {",
                  "  $('#my_tooltip').show();",
                  "  var tooltip = document.getElementById('my_tooltip');",
                  "  var rect = tooltip.getBoundingClientRect();",
                  "  var hoverLeft = ", hover$left, ";",
                  "  var hoverTop = ", hover$top, ";",
                  "  var imgWidth = e.target.width;",
                  "  var imgHeight = e.target.height;",
                  "  var offX = 2*hoverLeft > imgWidth ? -rect.width : 0;",
                  "  var offY = 2*hoverTop > imgHeight ? -rect.height+30 : 30;",
                  "  $('#my_tooltip').css({",
                  "    top: e.offsetY + offY + 'px',",
                  "    left: e.offsetX + e.target.offsetLeft + offX + 'px'",
                  "  });",
                  "});") )

  })
```

---

## Edit

To be sure the tooltip does not go outside the plotting area:

```
runjs(paste0( "$('[id=FP1PlotDoubleplot]').off('mousemove.x').on('mousemove.x', function(e) {",
              "  $('#my_tooltip').show();",
              "  var tooltip = document.getElementById('my_tooltip');",
              "  var rect = tooltip.getBoundingClientRect();",
              "  var hoverLeft = ", hover$left, ";",
              "  var hoverTop = ", hover$top, ";",
              "  var imgWidth = e.target.width;",
              "  var imgHeight = e.target.height;",
              "  var offX = 2*hoverLeft > imgWidth ? -rect.width : 0;",
              "  var offY = 2*hoverTop > imgHeight ? -rect.height+30 : 30;",
              "  var shiftY = e.offsetY + offY;",
              "  shiftY = shiftY + rect.height > imgHeight ? 20 + imgHeight - rect.height : shiftY;",
              "  shiftY = Math.max(20, shiftY);",
              "  $('#my_tooltip').css({",
              "    top: shiftY + 'px',",
              "    left: e.offsetX + e.target.offsetLeft + offX + 'px'",
              "  });",
              "});") )
```

---

## Edit

I have tried with four plots arranged on two rows. Here is my solution.

```
require('shiny')
require('ggplot2')
require('DT')
require('shinyjs')
library('shinyBS')

ui <- pageWithSidebar(

  headerPanel("Hover off the page"),
  sidebarPanel(),
  mainPanel(
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
    tags$head(
      tags$style('
                 #my_tooltip {
                 position: absolute;
                 pointer-events:none;
                 width: 10;
                 z-index: 100;
                 padding: 0;
                 font-size:10px;
                 line-height:0.6em
                 }
                 ')
    ),

    uiOutput('FP1PlotDoubleplot'),

    uiOutput('my_tooltip'),
    style = 'width:1250px'
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # ranges <- reactiveValues()


  output$FP1Plot1 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, color = as.factor(cyl))) + geom_point() 
  })

  output$FP1Plot2 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, color = as.factor(cyl))) + geom_point() 
  })

  output$FP1Plot3 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, color = as.factor(cyl))) + geom_point() 
  })

  output$FP1Plot4 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, color = as.factor(cyl))) + geom_point() 
  })

  output$FP1PlotDoubleplot<- renderUI({

    tagList(
      fluidRow(
        column(6, 
               wellPanel(
                 plotOutput('FP1Plot1',
                            width = 500,
                            height = 400,
                            hover = hoverOpts(id = paste('FP1Plot', 1, "hover", sep = '_'), delay = 0)
                 ),
                 style = 'border-color:#339fff; border-width:2px; background-color: #fff;'
               )
        ),
        column(6, 
               wellPanel(
                 plotOutput('FP1Plot2',
                            width = 500,
                            height = 400,
                            hover = hoverOpts(id = paste('FP1Plot', 2, "hover", sep = '_'), delay = 0)
                 ),
                 style = 'border-color:#339fff; border-width:2px; background-color: #fff;'
               )
        )
      ),
      fluidRow(
        column(6, 
               wellPanel(
                 plotOutput('FP1Plot3',
                            width = 500,
                            height = 400,
                            hover = hoverOpts(id = paste('FP1Plot', 3, "hover", sep = '_'), delay = 0)
                 ),
                 style = 'border-color:#339fff; border-width:2px; background-color: #fff;'
               )
        ),
        column(6, 
               wellPanel(
                 plotOutput('FP1Plot4',
                            width = 500,
                            height = 400,
                            hover = hoverOpts(id = paste('FP1Plot', 4, "hover", sep = '_'), delay = 0)
                 ),
                 style = 'border-color:#339fff; border-width:2px; background-color: #fff;'
               )
        )
      )
    )
  })


  # turn the hovers into 1 single reactive containing the needed information
  hoverReact <- reactive({
    eg <- expand.grid(c('FP1Plot'), 1:4)
    plotids <- sprintf('%s_%s', eg[,1], eg[,2])
    names(plotids) <- plotids

    hovers <- lapply(plotids, function(key) input[[paste0(key, '_hover')]])

    notNull <- sapply(hovers, Negate(is.null))
    if(any(notNull)){
      plotid <- names(which(notNull))
      plothoverid <- paste0(plotid, "_hover")

      hover <- input[[plothoverid]]
      if(is.null(hover)) return(NULL)
      hover
    }
  })

  ## debounce the reaction to calm down shiny
  hoverReact_D <- hoverReact %>% debounce(100)  ## attempt to stop hoverData <- reactive({}) from firing too often, which is needed when you have 10k point scatter plots.....

  hoverData <- reactive({
    hover <- hoverReact_D() 
    if(is.null(hover)) return(NULL)
    ## in my multi plot multi data frame I look up which dataframe to grab based on hover$plot_id as well as which x and y parameter are plotted
    hoverDF <- nearPoints(mtcars, coordinfo = hover, threshold = 15, maxpoints = 1, xvar = 'wt', yvar = 'mpg')
    hoverDF
  })

  hoverPos <- reactive({
    ## here I look up the position information of the hover whenevver hoverReact_D and hoverData change 
    hover <- hoverReact_D()
    hoverDF <- hoverData()
    if(is.null(hover)) return(NULL)
    if(nrow(hoverDF) == 0) return(NULL)

    ## in my real app the data is already 
    X <- hoverDF$wt[1]
    Y <- hoverDF$mpg[1]

    left_pct <- 
      (X - hover$domain$left) / (hover$domain$right - hover$domain$left)

    top_pct <- 
      (hover$domain$top - Y) / (hover$domain$top - hover$domain$bottom)  

    left_px <- 
      (hover$range$left + left_pct * (hover$range$right - hover$range$left)) / 
      hover$img_css_ratio$x 

    top_px <- 
      (hover$range$top + top_pct * (hover$range$bottom - hover$range$top)) / 
      hover$img_css_ratio$y 

    list(top = top_px, left = left_px)
  })




  observeEvent(hoverPos(), {
    req(hoverPos())
    hover <- hoverPos()
    if(is.null(hover)) return(NULL)

    runjs(paste0( "$('[id=FP1PlotDoubleplot]').off('mousemove.x').on('mousemove.x', function(e) {",
                  "  $('#my_tooltip').show();",
                  "  var tooltip = document.getElementById('my_tooltip');",
                  "  var rect = tooltip.getBoundingClientRect();",
                  "  var hoverLeft = ", hover$left, ";",
                  "  var hoverTop = ", hover$top, ";",
                  "  var imgWidth = e.target.width;",
                  "  var imgHeight = e.target.height;",
                  "  var offX = 2*hoverLeft > imgWidth ? -rect.width : 0;",
                  "  var offY = 2*hoverTop > imgHeight ? -rect.height+20 : 0;",
                  "  var shiftY = e.offsetY + offY;",
                  "  shiftY = shiftY + rect.height > imgHeight ? imgHeight - rect.height : shiftY;",
                  "  shiftY = Math.max(0, shiftY);",
                  "  $('#my_tooltip').css({",
                  "    top: shiftY + e.target.getBoundingClientRect().top - document.getElementById('FP1PlotDoubleplot').getBoundingClientRect().top + 'px',",
                  "    left: e.clientX + offX + 'px'",
                  "  });",
                  "});") )

  })

  output$GGHoverTable <- DT::renderDataTable({  

    df <- hoverData()
    if(!is.null(df)) {
      if(nrow(df)){
        df <- df[1,]
        DT::datatable(t(df), colnames = rep("", nrow(df)),
                      options = list(dom='t',ordering=F))
      }
    }
  })


  output$my_tooltip <- renderUI({
    req(hoverData())
    req(nrow(hoverData())>0 )
    wellPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput('GGHoverTable'),
      style = 'background-color: #FFFFFFE6;padding:10px; width:400px;border-color:#339fff; width:auto')  
  })  

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Ah great! Wonderful that there is a target.offset functionality. I am guessing that there is a similar one for when I have 2 or more rows of plots? e.target.offsetTop perhaps?

Comment: @Mark Yes, there is e.target.offsetTop

Comment: Ok, ill test if the nr of pixels needed for the offset stays the same for changing nr of plots. The size of the total multi plot layout is fixed by the way in my app, and the single plots are scaled to fit the area

Comment: One more thing, it would be even move fancy of course if we can use the pixel size of the hover message to calculate the offsets on, seeing that the content of the message might change. Do you know a clever javascript to collect that w*h info ?

Comment: looks cool. I'm going to be travelling the rest of the day so will get back to this tomorrow. First glance, this new edit won't be able to deal with change in 1,2,3 or 4 columns will it, since offX (and offY) are merely something / 2 which only works for 2 columns

Comment: @Stefane, I added code to store the height and width per subplot in reactive variables in order to do the `>` comparison based on half of those values, which works nicely, but I think we need to add 4 more statements. i.e. if the code decides to flip the message in upward orientation, we would need to check if there is enough room between the mouse location, and the top of the grouped object. When flipped downward, whether there is enough room between mouse pos. and bottom of grouped object, to really make sure it always fits. 
My attempt looked like this:

Comment: ` "  offY = e.offsetY +e.target.offsetTop + rect.height +30 >= 600 ? -rect.height +30 :offY;"`    Would this be correct for limiting downward scenarios, and how to do this for upward? Ideally replacing the 600 with the actual size of the multiplot object

Comment: @Mark See my edit. This JS code automatically gets the dimensions of the plot. That does not answer your question; you mean you want to vertically shift the tooltip if there's no enough room ?

Comment: @ Stephane, yes indeed. I tried your new code, but it's got some issues with it. I posted a new question with examples to explain better here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57101397/flexibel-location-of-hover-message-while-preventing-message-to-reach-beyond-obje

Comment: @Mark For me the latest app I posted is fine. I've done in such a way that a tooltip never goes outside the plotting area of the plot it refers to. I've seen your new question. In fact, for you, the "plotting area" is the area occupied by the four plots, if I correctly understand.

Comment: After more playing around I have now adopted a script that seems to do the job very well. There is just one thing left. I noticed that the values added in the lines ` var offX =  .... `  and ` var offY = .....`  changes with changes in where on the page the overal grouped plot div is placed. I wonder if there is another target like e.offsetY and e.target.offsetY to calculate what this nr should be. (see update #4 above)