# Flexibel location of hover message while preventing message to reach beyond object limits

Tags: javascript, css, r, ggplot2, hover

In an app with dynamic number of plots rendered and scaled inside a fixed `div` I'm trying to solve the final scenario, where in an arrangement of plots over multiple columns and multiple rows, the message should not end up going outside the grouping object.

In an attempt to make hover messages over `ggplots` I have so far achieved the following with previous questions:

Hover over a single plot without going off screen  [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57039988/how-to-prevent-ggplot-hoveropts-messages-to-go-off-screen-with-css)
i.e. 
Hover over multiple plots [Question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57075496/location-of-hover-message-when-there-are-multiple-plots-goes-wrong)
and an attempt to improve the correction for going off screen. I posted the current best working version there, and then tried to use the last edit posted in the comments there, but the code seems to be correcting a bit too much. **The message almost always ends up vertically centered above the top row plot**.

- instead of correcting when the message would overlap the entire multi panel, it seems to react to overlapping the bottom of any single plot
- the correction sends it to coordinates in the top row of plots rather than the relevant row of plots we are hovering over.

That version of the javascript (not working a intended) looks like this currently:

```
 runjs(paste0( "$('[id=FP1PlotMultiplot]').off('mousemove.x').on('mousemove.x', function(e) {",
                "  $('#my_tooltip').show();",
                "  var tooltip = document.getElementById('my_tooltip');",
                "  var rect = tooltip.getBoundingClientRect();",
                "  var hoverLeft = ", hover$left, ";",
                "  var hoverTop = ", hover$top, ";",
                "  var imgWidth = e.target.width;",
                "  var imgHeight = e.target.height;",
                "  var offX = 2*hoverLeft > imgWidth ? -rect.width : 0;",
                "  var offY = 2*hoverTop > imgHeight ? -rect.height+30 : 30;",
                "  var shiftY = e.offsetY + offY;",
                "  shiftY = shiftY + rect.height > imgHeight ? 20 + imgHeight - rect.height : shiftY;",
                "  shiftY = Math.max(20, shiftY);",
                "  $('#my_tooltip').css({",
                "    top: shiftY + 'px',",
                "    left: e.offsetX + e.target.offsetLeft + offX + 'px'",
                "  });",
                "});") )
```

Which in a way is nice that we don't need to predetermine any sizes, but as the images below show, doesn't exactly do what I am looking for.

[image: example]

[image: example2]

[image: example3]

The previous version worked nice for flipping the plots, but did not check whether the message would actually fit after flipping it between the anchor point and the edge of the multiplot object (`FP1PlotMultiplot`)

```
  #width per plot = 1000 / nr of cols
  #height per plot = 600 / nr of rows
Ylim <- 250  # half of the height per plot
Ylim <- 150 #half the height per plot

offX <- if(hover$left  > Xlim) {1000} else {30} 
offY <- if(hover$top  > Ylim) {1000} else {50}

runjs(paste0( "$('[id=FP1PlotMultiplot]').off('mousemove.x').on('mousemove.x', function(e) {",
              "  $('#my_tooltip').show();",
              "  var tooltip = document.getElementById('my_tooltip');",
              "  var rect = tooltip.getBoundingClientRect();",
              "  var offX = ", offX, ";",
              "  var offY = ", offY, ";",
              "  offX = offX === 1000 ? -rect.width : offX;",
              "  offY = offY === 1000 ? -rect.height +30 : offY;",
              "  offY = e.offsetY +e.target.offsetTop + rect.height >= 640 ? -rect.height +30 :offY;",
              "  $('#my_tooltip').css({",
              "    top: e.offsetY + e.target.offsetTop + offY + 'px',",
              "    left: e.offsetX + e.target.offsetLeft + offX + 'px'",
              "  });",
              "});") )
```

**FULL Test app showing the "nearly working"  version**

```
 require('shiny')
  require('ggplot2')
  require('DT')
  require('shinyjs')
  library('shinyBS')

  ui <- pageWithSidebar(

    headerPanel("Hover off the page"),
    sidebarPanel(width = 2,

                 verbatimTextOutput('leftPix'),
                 verbatimTextOutput('topPix')
    ),
    mainPanel(
      shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
      tags$head(
        tags$style('
                   #my_tooltip {
                   position: absolute;
                   pointer-events:none;
                   width: 10;
                   z-index: 100;
                   padding: 0;
                   font-size:10px;
                   line-height:0.6em
                   }
                   ')
        ),

      uiOutput('FP1PlotMultiplot'),

      uiOutput('my_tooltip'),
      style = 'width:1250px'
        )
      )

  server <- function(input, output, session) {


    output$FP1Plot_1 <- renderPlot({
      ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, color = as.factor(cyl))) + geom_point() +
        theme(legend.position = "none")
    })

    output$FP1Plot_2 <- renderPlot({
      ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, color = as.factor(cyl))) + geom_point() +
        theme(legend.position = "none")
      })

    output$FP1Plot_3 <- renderPlot({
      ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, color = as.factor(cyl))) + geom_point() +
        theme(legend.position = "none")
    })

    output$FP1Plot_4 <- renderPlot({
      ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, color = as.factor(cyl))) + geom_point() +
        theme(legend.position = "none")
    })

    output$FP1PlotMultiplot<- renderUI({


      plot_output_list <- list()

      for(i in 1:4) {
        plot_output_list <- append(plot_output_list,list(
          div(id = paste0('div', 'FP1Plot_', i),
              wellPanel(
                plotOutput(paste0('FP1Plot_', i),
                           width = 500,
                           height = 300,
                           hover = hoverOpts(id = paste('FP1Plot', i, "hover", sep = '_'), delay = 0)
                ),
                style = paste('border-color:#339fff; border-width:2px; background-color: #fff; width:',  540, 'px; height:', 340, 'px', sep = '')),
              style = paste('display: inline-block; margin: 2px; width:', 540, 'px; height:', 340, 'px', sep = ''))

        ))
      }
      do.call(tagList, plot_output_list)

    })








    # turn the hovers into 1 single reactive containing the needed information
    hoverReact <- reactive({
      eg <- expand.grid(c('FP1Plot'), 1:4)
      plotids <- sprintf('%s_%s', eg[,1], eg[,2])
      names(plotids) <- plotids

      hovers <- lapply(plotids, function(key) input[[paste0(key, '_hover')]])

      notNull <- sapply(hovers, Negate(is.null))
      if(any(notNull)){
        plotid <- names(which(notNull))
        plothoverid <- paste0(plotid, "_hover")

        hover <- input[[plothoverid]]
        if(is.null(hover)) return(NULL)
        hover
      }
    })

    ## debounce the reaction to calm down shiny
    hoverReact_D <- hoverReact %>% debounce(100)  ## attempt to stop hoverData <- reactive({}) from firing too often, which is needed when you have 10k point scatter plots.....

    hoverData <- reactive({
      hover <- hoverReact_D() 
      if(is.null(hover)) return(NULL)
      ## in my multi plot multi data frame I look up which dataframe to grab based on hover$plot_id as well as which x and y parameter are plotted
      hoverDF <- nearPoints(mtcars, coordinfo = hover, threshold = 15, maxpoints = 1, xvar = 'wt', yvar = 'mpg')
      hoverDF
    })



    hoverPos <- reactive({
      ## here I look up the position information of the hover whenevver hoverReact_D and hoverData change 
      hover <- hoverReact_D()
      hoverDF <- hoverData()
      if(is.null(hover)) return(NULL)
      if(nrow(hoverDF) == 0) return(NULL)

      ## in my real app the data is already 
      X <- hoverDF$wt[1]
      Y <- hoverDF$mpg[1]

      left_pct <- 
        (X - hover$domain$left) / (hover$domain$right - hover$domain$left)

      top_pct <- 
        (hover$domain$top - Y) / (hover$domain$top - hover$domain$bottom)  

      left_px <- 
        (hover$range$left + left_pct * (hover$range$right - hover$range$left)) / 
        hover$img_css_ratio$x 

      top_px <- 
        (hover$range$top + top_pct * (hover$range$bottom - hover$range$top)) / 
        hover$img_css_ratio$y 

      list(top = top_px, left = left_px)
    })




    observeEvent(hoverPos(), {
      req(hoverPos())
      hover <- hoverPos()
      if(is.null(hover)) return(NULL)

      #width per plot = 1000 / nr of cols
      #height per plot = 600 / nr of rows
      offX <- if(hover$left  > 250) {1000} else {30} # 270 = 540/2 (540 is the width of FP1PlotDoubleplot)
      offY <- if(hover$top  > 150) {1000} else {50}



      runjs(paste0( "$('[id=FP1PlotMultiplot]').off('mousemove.x').on('mousemove.x', function(e) {",
                    "  $('#my_tooltip').show();",
                    "  var tooltip = document.getElementById('my_tooltip');",
                    "  var rect = tooltip.getBoundingClientRect();",
                    "  var hoverLeft = ", hover$left, ";",
                    "  var hoverTop = ", hover$top, ";",
                    "  var imgWidth = e.target.width;",
                    "  var imgHeight = e.target.height;",
                    "  var offX = 2*hoverLeft > imgWidth ? -rect.width : 0;",
                    "  var offY = 2*hoverTop > imgHeight ? -rect.height+30 : 30;",
                    "  var shiftY = e.offsetY + offY;",
                    "  shiftY = shiftY + rect.height > imgHeight ? 20 + imgHeight - rect.height : shiftY;",
                    "  shiftY = Math.max(20, shiftY);",
                    "  $('#my_tooltip').css({",
                    "    top: shiftY + 'px',",
                    "    left: e.offsetX + e.target.offsetLeft + offX + 'px'",
                    "  });",
                    "});") )

      })

    output$GGHoverTable <- DT::renderDataTable({  

      df <- hoverData()
      if(!is.null(df)) {
        if(nrow(df)){
          df <- df[1,]
          DT::datatable(t(df), colnames = rep("", nrow(df)),
                        options = list(dom='t',ordering=F))
        }
      }
    })


    output$my_tooltip <- renderUI({
      req(hoverData())
      req(nrow(hoverData())>0 )
      wellPanel(
        DT::dataTableOutput('GGHoverTable'),
        style = 'background-color: #FFFFFFE6;padding:10px; width:400px;border-color:#339fff; width:auto')  
    })  

  }

  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I managed to get it working with some more modification: 
It now includes an if statement to check if the result doesn't cause coordinates for the anchor point to be either <0 or >object height

The only thing I would still want to change (if possible is the references to `FP1PlotMultiplot` inside the javascript because I want to apply this script to 7 different objects where their names are only listed in the first line of the javascript like this:

`$('[id=FP1PlotMultiplot], [id=FP2PlotMultiplot],[id=CRFPlotMultiplot]').off('mousemove.x').on('mousemove.x', ......`

so, to replace the name based approach by something similar to 'e.target'  but then for the main output object's ID

```
  runjs(paste0( "$('[id=FP1PlotMultiplot]').off('mousemove.x').on('mousemove.x', function(e) {",
                  "  $('#my_tooltip').show();",
                  "  var tooltip = document.getElementById('my_tooltip');",
                  "  var rect = tooltip.getBoundingClientRect();",
                  "  var FrameID = document.getElementById('FP1PlotMultiplot');",
                  "  var frame = FrameID.getBoundingClientRect();",
                  "  var hoverLeft = ", hover$left, ";",
                  "  var hoverTop = ", hover$top, ";", 
                  "  var imgWidth = e.target.width;",
                  "  var imgHeight = e.target.height;",
                  "  var offX = 2 * hoverLeft > imgWidth ? -rect.width -10 : 10;",
                  "  var offY = 2 * hoverTop > imgHeight ? -rect.height + 10 : 10;",
                  "  var shiftY = e.offsetY + e.target.offsetTop + offY;",
                  "  if (offY === 10) {",
                  "  shiftY = shiftY + rect.height > frame.height ? -rect.height + 10 + e.offsetY + e.target.offsetTop : shiftY",
                  "  } else {",
                  "  shiftY = shiftY < 0 ? e.offsetY + e.target.offsetTop + 10 : shiftY",
                  "  };",
                  "  $('#my_tooltip').css({",
                  "    top: shiftY + 'px',",
                  "    left: e.offsetX + e.target.offsetLeft + offX + 'px'",
                  "  });",
                  "});") )
```

**UPDATE: current version, last remaining issues**

Below is the current best working version. There are a few issues I'm still trying to improve.

1) When the code decides to flip the message upward, but there is only 1 plot, the shiftY value can currently result in a position that is above the top edge of the total plot object such as here: 
[image: Problem 1]
and then deciding to put it downwards, with 1 plot it can reach beyond the bottom. 
[image]

The cause of this is that the message doesn't fit upward or downward from the current hover place, and somehow the javascript needs another rule to figure this out, and if so, place the message i.e. 10 pixels below the top of total object. I tried various things, but I either ended up with messages always in the same place, or no result, as I couldn't quite figure out how to calculate whether the message ends up above, or below the total plot area after the current `if (offY ...` statement to determin shiftY.

2) The second major issue is that the app seems to get hung up on calculating new tables if the user moves the mouse a lot (in a plot with a few thousand data points this becomes more evident). So, if the mouse went from point A to point, the code reacts to a lot of hover positions between A and B causing a long queue of calculations to be triggered before finally showing the actual information of point B where the mouse 'stopped'  or paused. I have been playing with delay and debounce, but did not find a working solution to stop the app from going through unnecessary calculations, which in my real app are more intensive /demanding on R than the test app.

**Current version demo app:**

```
require('shiny')
require('ggplot2')
require('DT')
require('shinyjs')
library('shinyBS')

ui <- pageWithSidebar(

  headerPanel("Hover off the page"),
  sidebarPanel(width = 2,
               sliderInput(inputId = 'NrOfPlots', label = 'Nr of Plots', min = 1, max = 20, value = 1),
               verbatimTextOutput('leftPix'),
               verbatimTextOutput('topPix')
  ),
  mainPanel(
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
    tags$head(
      tags$style('
                 #my_tooltip {
                 position: absolute;
                 pointer-events:none;
                 width: 10;
                 z-index: 100;
                 padding: 0;
                 font-size:10px;
                 line-height:0.6em
                 }
                 ')
      ),

    uiOutput('FP1PlotMultiplot'),

    uiOutput('my_tooltip'),
    style = 'width:1250px'
      )
    )

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observe({
  lapply(1:input$NrOfPlots, function(i) {
  output[[paste0('FP1Plot_', i)]] <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, color = as.factor(cyl))) + geom_point() +
      theme(legend.position = "none")
})
  })
  })

  output$FP1PlotMultiplot<- renderUI({

    n <- input$NrOfPlots

    n_cols <- if(n == 1) {
      1
    } else if (n %in% c(2,4)) {
      2
    } else if (n %in% c(3,5,6,9)) {
      3
    } else {
      4
    }

    Pwidth <- 1000/n_cols
    Pheight <- 450/ceiling(n/n_cols) # calculate number of rows
    Pwidth2 <- Pwidth+40
    Pheight2 <- Pheight+80

    plot_output_list <- list()

    for(i in 1:input$NrOfPlots) {
      plot_output_list <- append(plot_output_list,list(
        div(id = paste0('div', 'FP1Plot_', i),
            wellPanel(
              plotOutput(paste0('FP1Plot_', i),
                         width = Pwidth,
                         height = Pheight,
                         hover = hoverOpts(id = paste('FP1Plot', i, "hover", sep = '_'), delay = 0)
              ),
              style = paste('border-color:#339fff; border-width:2px; background-color: #fff; width:',  Pwidth2, 'px; height:', Pheight2, 'px', sep = '')),
            style = paste('display: inline-block; margin: 2px; width:', Pwidth2, 'px; height:', Pheight2, 'px', sep = ''))

      ))
    }
    do.call(tagList, plot_output_list)

  })








  # turn the hovers into 1 single reactive containing the needed information
  hoverReact <- reactive({
    eg <- expand.grid(c('FP1Plot'), 1:input$NrOfPlots)
    plotids <- sprintf('%s_%s', eg[,1], eg[,2])
    names(plotids) <- plotids

    hovers <- lapply(plotids, function(key) input[[paste0(key, '_hover')]])

    notNull <- sapply(hovers, Negate(is.null))
    if(any(notNull)){
      plotid <- names(which(notNull))
      plothoverid <- paste0(plotid, "_hover")

      hover <- input[[plothoverid]]
      if(is.null(hover)) return(NULL)
      hover
    }
  })

  ## debounce the reaction to calm down shiny
  hoverReact_D <- hoverReact %>% debounce(100)  ## attempt to stop hoverData <- reactive({}) from firing too often, which is needed when you have 10k point scatter plots.....

  hoverData <- reactive({
    hover <- hoverReact_D() 
    if(is.null(hover)) return(NULL)
    ## in my multi plot multi data frame I look up which dataframe to grab based on hover$plot_id as well as which x and y parameter are plotted
    hoverDF <- nearPoints(mtcars, coordinfo = hover, threshold = 15, maxpoints = 1, xvar = 'wt', yvar = 'mpg')
    hoverDF
  })



  hoverPos <- reactive({
    ## here I look up the position information of the hover whenevver hoverReact_D and hoverData change 
    hover <- hoverReact_D()
    hoverDF <- hoverData()
    if(is.null(hover)) return(NULL)
    if(nrow(hoverDF) == 0) return(NULL)

    ## in my real app the data is already 
    X <- hoverDF$wt[1]
    Y <- hoverDF$mpg[1]

    left_pct <- 
      (X - hover$domain$left) / (hover$domain$right - hover$domain$left)

    top_pct <- 
      (hover$domain$top - Y) / (hover$domain$top - hover$domain$bottom)  

    left_px <- 
      (hover$range$left + left_pct * (hover$range$right - hover$range$left)) / 
      hover$img_css_ratio$x 

    top_px <- 
      (hover$range$top + top_pct * (hover$range$bottom - hover$range$top)) / 
      hover$img_css_ratio$y 

    list(top = top_px, left = left_px)
  })




  observeEvent(hoverPos(), {
    req(hoverPos())
    hover <- hoverPos()
    if(is.null(hover)) return(NULL)



    runjs(paste0( "$('[id=FP1PlotMultiplot]').off('mousemove.x').on('mousemove.x', function(e) {",
                  "  $('#my_tooltip').show();",
                  "  var tooltip = document.getElementById('my_tooltip');",
                  "  var rect = tooltip.getBoundingClientRect();",
                  "  var FrameID = document.getElementById('FP1PlotMultiplot');",
                  "  var frame = FrameID.getBoundingClientRect();",
                  "  var hoverLeft = ", hover$left, ";",
                  "  var hoverTop = ", hover$top, ";", 
                  "  var imgWidth = e.target.width;",
                  "  var imgHeight = e.target.height;",
                  "  var offX = 2 * hoverLeft > imgWidth ? -rect.width -10 : 10;",
                  "  var offY = 2 * hoverTop > imgHeight ? -rect.height + 10 : 10;",
                  "  var shiftY = e.offsetY + e.target.offsetTop + offY;",
                  "  if (offY === 10) {",
                  "  shiftY = shiftY + rect.height > frame.height ? -rect.height + 10 + e.offsetY + e.target.offsetTop : shiftY",
                  "  } else {",
                  "  shiftY = shiftY < 0 ? e.offsetY + e.target.offsetTop + 10 : shiftY",
                  "  };",
                  "  $('#my_tooltip').css({",
                  "    top: shiftY + 'px',",
                  "    left: e.offsetX + e.target.offsetLeft + offX + 'px'",
                  "  });",
                  "});") )

  })

  output$GGHoverTable <- renderTable({  

    df <- hoverData()
    if(!is.null(df)) {
      if(nrow(df)){
        df <- df[1,]
       t(df)
      }
    }
  })


  output$my_tooltip <- renderUI({
    req(hoverData())
    req(nrow(hoverData())>0 )
    wellPanel(
      tableOutput('GGHoverTable'),
      style = 'background-color: #FFFFFFE6;padding:10px; width:400px;border-color:#339fff; width:auto')  
  })  

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I think you can replace `document.getElementById('FP1PlotMultiplot');` with `e.currentTarget`.

Comment: Great. I switched to plane tableOutput and renderTable which seemed to improve the speed a lot. Thanks for all the help Stephane